# CoreData+CloudKit iOS13 NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ios13

I am using CoreData+CloudKit `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to automatically sync data to `CloudKit`.

I have been looking at Sample App provided by Apple on how to listen for remote store change notification and read the history change. After implementing the same I have noticed that `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification` gets fired multiple times. On every App launch even if there is no change in data, the history change shows insertion to all the entities, which is really confusing.

How can you reliably check that there are actually records being added to the entity? And Also how to deal with multiple notifications being fired at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of `NSPersistentHistoryToken` to keep track of the most recent history that you’ve processed. Set a transaction during your save and use `NSPersistentHistoryTransaction`'s predicate to only fetch other authors.

For more more detail see "Keep Track of Your Place in the History" in [Consuming Relevant Store Changes.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes?language=objc)